# Portfolio Optimization using non-linear optimizer

Tags: r, solver, portfolio, nonlinear-optimization, quantitative-finance

I have been attempting to optimize a portfolio (max return subject to target risk) of returns using a known mu and covariance matrix subject to box and group constraints. It seems that the best solution is to create my own function using the 'Rdonlp2' package. However, when testing this package under very basic (long only) constraints it only produces an equal weighted portfolio. When I added a box and group constraint, it produced an equal weighted portfolio subject to the box constraint but did not register the group constraint.

```
install.packages("fPortfolio")
install.packages("Rdonlp2", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

If you do not already have the packages ^

```
library(fPortfolio)
library(Rdonlp2)
lppData=100*LPP2005.RET[,1:6]
mr1Spec = portfolioSpec()
setTargetRisk(mr1Spec) = 0.1
setSolver(mr1Spec) = "solveRdonlp2"

efficientPortfolio(data=lppData, spec=mr1Spec, constraints="LongOnly")
efficientPortfolio(data=lppData, spec=mr1Spec, constraints= c("maxsum[1:6]=.75", "maxW[1:6]=.1"))
```

has anyone had success using this optimizer? any help getting the portfolio to optimize correctly or setting up my own function would be greatly appreciated!

@WaltS
If I use only box constraints and don't specify the optimizer I get a solution (code below)

```
library(fPortfolio)
lppData=100*LPP2005.RET[,1:6]
mr1Spec = portfolioSpec()
portfolioFrontier(data=lppData, spec=mr1Spec, constraints=c("minW[1:6]=-1", "maxW[1:6]=2"))
```

However If I add group constraints...

```
portfolioFrontier(data=lppData, spec=mr1Spec, constraints= c("maxsumW[1:6]=.2", "maxsumW[1:6]=.75"))
```

and run it, it produces the following error...

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("SBI", "SPI", "SII", "LMI", "MPI",  : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

In the box only case, do you if its possible to call the portfolio weights corresponding to the vol closest to .15, which would be a var of about .38?

Comment: Assuming risk is measured by portfolio variance, have you considered solving for the efficient frontier with box and group constraints and then obtaining the return for a given level of risk from that?  There are several ways to effectively solve for the efficient frontier in R.

Comment: What is the shape and source of lppData?  Please add all required code to make this snippet reproducible.

Comment: @chollida , if you look at the top, to reproduce this requires the fPortfolio packages, lppData comes from a sample dataset within fPortfolio, but I'll insert it at the top of the latest snippet.